# can't find how to align an element in a fragment to center of the screen without changing the container's height to match parent [xml question]

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

let's start from the main activity. my main activity has a fragment container with height set to wrap content and is enclosed inside a scroll view. The scroll view fills the screen.

[this is why I can't set it to match parent. because other fragments wont fit then. Also, I can't set the first fragment as a separate activity because this is a part of a training project and most of it was already built with tests in place.]

The first fragment I have has a single button in it and that fragment's height is set to match parent [which is the container with wrap content].

the button inside the fragment is aligned to the centre of the screen for its fragment xml. but, since wrap is enabled for the container, the button is now at the top in the main activity.

now, setting the height for the fragment as some fixed value might solve the problem when the height of the device is fixed. but, in other cases, the button's location might not be shown as wanted.

You will find a screenshot below which will give you a better understanding of my problem.

[image: android studio screen shot]

the top is the fragment layout while the bottom is the main activity layout. all I want is the button to be at the centre of the screen regardless of the screen size.

main acivity -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TODO: Add a FragmentContainerView with navigation/mobile_navigation as the navHost -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment activity -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_start_order"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.order.StartOrderFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_order_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/base_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/base_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/base_margin"
        android:text="@string/start_order"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I also tried turning the fragment layout into a binding layout and setting the height manually. but, it's giving a val cannot be assigned error. [the same binding variable allows me to change the button text.] the screenshot below is of the same attempt.

[image: kotlin attempt image]

the same kotlin code as above -

```
package com.example.lunchtray.ui.order

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.lunchtray.R
import com.example.lunchtray.databinding.FragmentStartOrderBinding

class StartOrderFragment : Fragment() {

    // Binding object instance corresponding to the fragment_start_order.xml layout
    // This property is non-null between the onCreateView() and onDestroyView() lifecycle callbacks,
    // when the view hierarchy is attached to the fragment.
    private var _binding: FragmentStartOrderBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentStartOrderBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root
        // Navigate to entree menu
        binding.startOrderBtn.setOnClickListener {
            // TODO: navigate to the EntreeMenuFragment
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_startOrderFragment_to_entreeMenuFragment)
        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.layoutStartOrder.height = 1 //error
        binding.startOrderBtn.text = "wwmfkkf" //so, binding variable isn't the problem
        //todo - remove button text assignment
    }

    /**
     * This fragment lifecycle method is called when the view hierarchy associated with the fragment
     * is being removed. As a result, clear out the binding object.
     */
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Any form of help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Did you try setting ScrollView height to 0dp?

Comment: that doesn't make a difference because th scroll view already fills the entire screen. [yes I tried]. I just want the size of the fragment to be as much as it's container. but, since the container is in a scroll view, it's height is set to wrap_content. So, now the button is at the top because the scroll view starts from the top and the fragment activity doesn't fill the screen [because wrap_content is enabled]. I tried setting the fragment's height in kotlin code. but, the code returns the screen size instead of the fragment container size which makes fragment size exceed the scroll limit.

Comment: Add `android:layout_gravity="center"` to FragmentContainerView element.

Comment: I only want one individual fragment to fill the screen. the rest have to start from the top. so, basically, if possible, I want to set that fragment's height to just match it's parent[container] so that the fragment fits perfectly in the scroll view and is not scrollable this would also automatically centre the button. but, match parent cannot be implemented to the fragment view file because the fragment container is inside a scroll view and elements inside scroll view cannot have their height to match parent. so, instead it just wraps itself ass seen in the above pic of main activity.